# PHP Removing parenthesis from string element inside of array

Tags: php, arrays, trim

I am using `in_array()` function and `trim()` in order to detect strings in my array that include parenthesis `()`. Although that my current program is operating and meets my needs I would like to take it to the next level and make it more generic. Currently I am specifying the array position through `"stack[2]"`.

```
$stack = array( "test-1" , "test-2" , "(test-3)" );

print_r($stack);

if ( in_array( "".$stack[2]."" , $stack , TRUE ) ) {
  $stack[2] = trim($stack[2], '()');
}

print_r($stack);
```

Before the trimming process:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test-1
    [1] => test-2
    [2] => (test-3)
)
```

After the trimming process:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test-1
    [1] => test-2
    [2] => test-3
)
```

I would like my program to search each value in the array, remove the `()` and save it on the same position. Sample of a test array is provided below:

```
$stack = array( "test-1" , "test-2" , "(test-3)" , "test-4" , "(test-5)" );
```

I am sure there is a way but I can not figure it how to do it.

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: What do you mean you can't figure out how to do it? There a gajillion results when you google "remove parentheses from string php"

Comment: Use a `for` loop.  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop and sizeof array:

```
$stack = array( "test-1" , "test-2" , "(test-3)" , "test-4" , "(test-5)" );

print_r($stack);

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($stack); $i++){
   $stack[$i] = trim($stack[$i], '()');
}

print_r($stack);
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end was extremely simple, I used `foreach()` and push the elements to a new array. So simple and the result as expected. Sample of code and output provided bellow:

```
$stack = array( "test-1" , "test-2" , "(test-3)" , "test-4" , "(test-5)" );

print_r($stack);
```

Output of `print_r()` before the loop:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test-1
    [1] => test-2
    [2] => (test-3)
    [3] => test-4
    [4] => (test-5)
)

$array = array();

foreach ($stack as $string) {
  $string = trim($string, '()');
  array_push($array, "".$string."");
}

print_r($array);
```

Output of the `print_r()` after the process:

```
Array
(
    [0] => test-1
    [1] => test-2
    [2] => test-3
    [3] => test-4
    [4] => test-5
)
```

Sorry for the so simple questions/answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stack = array( "test-1" , "test-2" , "(test-3)" , "test-4" , "(test-5)" );

for(i=0; i < count($stack); i++) {
  $stack[$i] = trim($stack[$i], '()');
}
```

I would suggest going and reading some tutorials on PHP programming.  This is a pretty basic idea.